# JodaTime method argument ignored using JAXB in web method

Tags: java, xml, soap, jaxb, jodatime

Using a SOAP client I can get the marshalling correct but not unmarshalling in the other end. So for this purpose I've been testing with SOAP UI calling this method with an argument "2013-05".

A breakpoint in the web method findByYearMonth shows a current date value and I can also see that the base constructor of YearMonth is called by JAXB binding (that's why I get 2014-02).

```
//The class with the web method
@Component
@Qualifier("myFacade")
@XmlJavaTypeAdapter(YearMonthAdapter.class)
@Service
public class myFacade implements IMyFacade {

    /*the web method */ 
    findByYearMonth(YearMonth yearMonth) throws MyException {
        // Break point here shows yearMonth = "2014-02"
    }
}
```

Adapter:

```
/**
 * The YearMonth adapter.
 *
 * XmlAdapter for YearMonth
 */
public class YearMonthAdapter extends XmlAdapter<String, YearMonth> {

    @Override
    public YearMonth unmarshal(String v) throws Exception {
        return YearMonth.parse(v);
   }

    @Override
    public String marshal(YearMonth v) throws Exception {
        return v.toString();
    }

}
```

If YearMonth is inside a DTO, and I pass that as an argument it works correctly - as long as I have the package-info.java file in the right path. I've tried many combinations and different annotations, and also have the following package-info.java file in the same package as the class that contains the web method, but I had no luck getting the web method to get the right value.

```
//package-info.java
@XmlJavaTypeAdapter(type = YearMonth.class, value = YearMonthAdapter.class)
package uk.co.imperatives.billing.core.summary;

import javax.xml.bind.annotation.adapters.XmlJavaTypeAdapter;

import org.joda.time.YearMonth;

import uk.co.imperatives.billing.api.util.YearMonthAdapter;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to annotate the parameter directly such as below:

```
//The class with the web method
@Component
@Qualifier("myFacade")
@Service
public class MyFacade implements IMyFacade {

    /* the web method */ 
    findByYearMonth(@XmlJavaTypeAdapter(type = YearMonth.class, value = YearMonthAdapter.class) YearMonth yearMonth) throws MyException {
        // Break point should now show yearMonth = "2013-05"
    }
}
```